# Unable to execute DSC file i n Windows server 2012 R2 from remote machine

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc

When I execute the command to machine I get the following error -

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $cimsession = New-CimSession -Credential (Get-Credential -UserName "test" -Message "test") -ComputerName test.cloudapp.net -Port 58718 -SessionOption $cimsessionoption

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-DscConfiguration -CimSession $cimsession

Get-DscConfiguration : Current configuration does not exist. Execute Start-DscConfiguration command with -Path parameter to specify a 
configuration file and create a current configuration first.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-DscConfiguration -CimSession $cimsession
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_DSCLocalConfigurationManager:root/Microsoft/...gurationManager) [Get-DscConfiguration],  
   CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 1,Get-DscConfiguration
    + PSComputerName        : powerlabdns.cloudapp.net
```

What does this mean?

Comment: I am updating my azure VM through powershell.I set the DSC extension with the below command  -

Comment: I am updating my azure VM through powershell.I set the DSC extension with the below command  - $Vm = Set-AzureVMDSCExtension -VM $Vm -ConfigurationArchive "IISInstall.ps1.zip" -ConfigurationName IISInstall and then and update the vm - $vm | Update-AzureVM. When I run the following command Get-AzureVMDscExtension -Vm $vm,

Comment: I get following result set - ModulesUrl            : https://chiazurenetwork.blob.core.windows.net/windows-powershell-dsc/IISInstall.ps1.zip
ConfigurationFunction : IISInstall.ps1\IISInstall
Properties            : {}
ExtensionName         : DSC
Publisher             : Microsoft.Powershell
Version               : 1.*
PrivateConfiguration  :

Comment: PublicConfiguration   : {"SasToken":"?sv=2014-02-14&sr=b&sig=QpKd51nR2%2FVJPp3Ev6dVcHmclQdXZwweKZ%2FAlEW5A7Y%3D&se=2015-01-16T01%3A16%3A45Z&sp=r","
                        ModulesUrl":"https://chiazurenetwork.blob.core.windows.net/windows-powershell-dsc/IISInstall.ps1.zip","ConfigurationFunctio
                        n":"IISInstall.ps1\\IISInstall","Properties":[],"ProtocolVersion":{"Major":2,"Minor":0,"Build":0,"Revision":0,"MajorRevisio
                        n":0,"MinorRevision":0}}
ReferenceName         : DSC
State                 : Enable
RoleName              : example-1

Comment: I assume when I update the VM , the script attached should get executed to my $vm. Is this right ?

Comment: You should edit your question and put these details in there and then delete your comments. That is the appropriate place for the information and it will be much easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

You are not executing a DSC file, you are requesting the current DSC configuration which does not exist (as the error says).

You need to run `Start-DscConfiguration` first, again as the error says to. You must pass a `-Path` to that call which is a directory (relative to the target node) where an MOF file (the compiled configuration) resides.

Once you do that, you'll be able to call `Get-DscConfiguration` to see the current config.

Comment: How would I know the relative path for the config file on my target code, as I passing it using powershell to my virtual azure machine. I have update the question section with more details, kindly refer that and do let me know if any more inputs to question is required.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't actually know how to use DSC with Azure. I know Azure has specific cmdlets for using DSC and I don't have a good picture of how that works. If this were not Azure, I would say that the config MOF needs to be locally on the target node or on a share that is accessible to it, and you would give it that path.